# Were the Ghost Twins killed in the explosion in Reloaded?

Tags: the-matrix

During the freeway chase scene in *The Matrix: Reloaded*, Morpheus stands his ground against the Ghost Twins as they drive towards him. He slices their vehicle, it loses balance, and as it rolls, he turns and shoots the underside of it, causing it to explode with the Twins still inside. The slow-motion effect implies this all happened very quickly, meaning that the Twins may not have had much time to react.

So, did Morpheus actually kill the Twins in that scene, or did they survive? As they were blown into the sky by the explosion, they "ghosted" in the final few frames of that camera angle, just before the camera cuts away, and that's the last we see of them; they also do not make an appearance in *The Matrix: Revolutions*.

[image: Ghost Twins "dying"?]

So did that scene of them "ghosting" after the explosion mean that they survived (since they've been shown to use "ghosting" to avoid taking damage and even to instantly recover from wounds), or was that supposed to show/represent them "dying"?

Answer (score 5):

[Yes, but they were recovered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twins_(The_Matrix)#Online). The MMORPG was considered canonical.

> In *The Matrix Online*, synthesised cheat codes based on those drunk by the Unlimit officer Beirn allowed the Merovingian to retrieve and reforge the fragmented and heavily dissipated RSIs of the Twins. His operatives were tasked with finding the partially reconstructed pieces, which were successfully secured and combined, returning the Twins to fully functional states.

Comment: I don't think *The Matrix Online* has been stated to be canonical by the Wachowskis or Warner, see [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144161/22250) on the complicated question of canon in the Matrix universe.

Comment: That's fair. I thought it was more strongly canonical, although much as with *Star Wars*, or Rowling's tweets, it's subject to change on whim.

Comment: What's an RSI here?

Comment: @Prometheus: [Residual Self Image](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Residual_self_image)