# Can you be invincible in the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

In the Matrix, you can do anything you believe you can do. Can you therefore be invincible in the Matrix? In real life games you can be invincible (like super star in Mario) and since the Matrix is a video game that you can change could you be invincible and win at everything?

Comment: I still haven't watched *The Matrix*, but my naive understanding is that this is basically what Neo does at the end of the movie.

Comment: The 'Twins' are essentially invincible; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEFfgO0bjtw

Comment: Username checks out.

Comment: @Möoz what does that mean?

Comment: "Smith" asking about invincibility in The Matrix, all makes sense :)

Comment: @Möoz oh, I get it. Lol, because my name is like Agent Smith.

Answer (score 5):

First off, you cannot just "believe" anything you want in the Matrix and have it come true. Like any virtual environment, there are rules. Someone had to program Mario's invincibility, for instance.

In the Matrix, Neo believes simply because he has faith in himself and his abilities. This makes him more confident. He simply has the skill, whether developed over time or some innate ability, to "visualise" the source code, see and understand the Matrix and its Agents on a different level, and even abuse the source code to a limited degree.

This is seen when Neo flies. It's not something anyone else does - not even the Agents themselves mostly. You could say that Neo learns how to abuse the source code of the Matrix. Thinking about it in programming parlance, he may have found an old "CanFly" boolean in the attributes of his own avatar and turned it to true. For stopping bullets, he may find the attributes of each bullet and turn its "Momentum" attribute to 0. He's making small modifications.

So far (I haven't seen Resurrections), he hasn't found a "MakeThisAvatarInvincible" attribute. Maybe there isn't one. Or even an "AvatarHitPoints". As such, he'd have to make some pretty hefty changes if he wanted to make himself invincible, probably rewriting (however that would be done) his own avatar so that, if anything hit him, make it deliver 0 hit points, or cause no damage. That would take a lot of time, not to mention the machines probably noticing.

Put simply, it seems that Neo can make "small" changes, and we don't know exactly what to and how. He can stop bullets, though we don't know exactly how - presumably turning their momentum to 0. However, it seems he can't stop big trucks, maybe because they're a lot more complicated objects - you can't simply stop one part of a truck at a time - or perhaps because they're much larger. Making himself invincible would be a lot more difficult.

Comment: your argument that Neo's powers are limited to those allowed by his surroundings works well with the scene in Mobil Ave station where Trainman easily defeats Neo. The Trainman is the architect of Mobil Ave station and he made himself have powers nobody else had and even Neo could not manipulate those rules.

Answer (score 0):

We see him lose initially to the army of Smith clones. In addition, he got a cut while blocking a sword with his hand.

Valorum mentioned the twins. However, even the twins are not invincible, as technically it is thought that Morpheus killed them in an explosion (though they later came back). See this [answer on this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236116/were-the-ghost-twins-killed-in-the-explosion-in-reloaded).

Lastly, any program/software (like the twins, Smith, Neo, Trinity, etc.) can be deleted. Even if the Matrix didn't let them be deleted, or even though Neo and Trinity exist in the real world, if the real world Neo and Trinity or person is killed, or if the physical Matrix is blown up, then anyone will die in the matrix.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not sure if the question is if _Neo_ is invincible, the question is more about if it is _possible_ for someone to become invincible.

Comment: @DavidW I was saying how no character was yet invincible

Comment: So since no character shown is invincible, and since the matrix itself can be destroyed, therefore based on Canon, there can be no invincibility

Comment: I'm not sure why we're accepting a magazine article as evidence of anything

Comment: @Valorum better?