# Whose bodies are the agents possessing when we first see them?

Tags: the-matrix

When the agents first appear while some cops are dying inside the Hearth O' The City Hotel at the hands of Trinity, whose body do they posess?

Except this scene, most of the time they consider the situation so bad that they outright possess a nearby body. In this case, however, they come by car. Do they have a dummy body for everyday situations?

[image: Agents]

Continuing to possess the last human they used would be risky because people would keep disappearing.

Comment: Maybe they are constantly busy? Perhaps they are simply inactive (incorporeal) when not needed? Good question!

Comment: Sort of related to the "last human they used" issue:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/what-happens-to-a-person-taken-over-by-an-agent-once-the-agent-voluntarily-leave

Answer (score 5):

**The bodies the Agents possess are simply unfortunates who happen to be nearby. They do not consider them dummy bodies, they just consider them tools to be used for the job. It is never made clear whether bodied possessed return to their lives unaware of having been used.**

In the Matrix before the start of the series, Agents were rarely if ever defeated, so there would be no reason to kill the host body once the Agent was finished using it. Likely these people would suffer from either a memory wipe or be treated as someone who had some sort of mild psychotic break.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough but I think you miss my point. I'm not asking what happens to the host person when they leave his/her body in general... I ask how is that they come by car this time here and the lieutenant recognizes them like they were possessing a single body for a longer time. It's a bit unlikely that it is a real human since A) the 3 host person who they use for a longer time would be missed B) if the agent ever needs to leave this "base" host urgently, if the host is a normal person, it could have disastrous side effects (others seeing the event, missing person found, etc).

Comment: The police seem to treat them as if they were government operatives like the CIA or FBI. They dress the part and of course, likely carry ID.

Comment: You're right, it wasn't a very strong point with the lieutenant. But they still come by car which is a lot slower way to get to the scene than possessing someone nearby. Why would they do that? + If the ones they possess are real CIA/FBI agents, then what are those doing there and what'll be in their reports? Who gave the 'specific orders' to the cops? If both side was tricked then their reports won't match. Or if they were the agents from the start then whose are the bodies?

Comment: All signs point to the possessed being returned to their bodies after their usefulness has ended; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12287/what-happens-to-a-person-taken-over-by-an-agent

Answer (score 1):

When Neo, Trinity, and the others 'dial in' to The Matrix a 'body' is created. It's simplest to assume that the Agents, having come from the machine city to The Matrix, albeit via another route, also create a body the first time they appear in The Matrix. Thus they are not possessing a person when they initially appear. This doesn't address what happens after they use a human host though, that is not covered in the films.

As for the car, the Agents have greater control over The Matrix so they should be able to create a car for themselves if they need one. After all if they can glitch the system to create walls over doors making a car should be no problem.

Comment: Cars are a bit more complicated than walls. I'm not sure that logic holds up.

Comment: @rsegal in `Enter the Matrix`, in the intro to the very first mission, it is clearly shown as the construct assembles for them a `pontiac firebird ho custom 1967` car.

Comment: @naxa oh, guess I was wrong. Thanks for keeping me honest.