# Agents dodging bullets in the Matrix

Tags: the-matrix

In the Matrix, especially the scene on the rooftop in part 1, when Neo is shooting at the agent who is dodging Neos shots using the 'bullet time' move the agent is only moving from the waist up. Why not shoot the agent in the legs also, what happens when you shoot an agent?

Comment: They shoot Neo in the leg. It's super-effective.

Comment: Shooting the legs is harder (smaller area), probably even easier to dodge. Besides that, I think this is very hard to answer with a canon answer. Also, it was the first time somebody was able to dodge bullets like that.

Comment: You see what happens when Trinity ("Dodge this!") shoots an Agent in the head. It disappears and turns back into the original person occupied by the Agent.

Comment: @Valorum forgot about the changing back. Has anyone asked if there is an original agent ie not a 'possessed' matrix dweller?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I will edit my question as I am asking about shooting at the agent, not at Neo

Comment: @Seamusthedog - I'm pretty sure that's a dupe

Comment: @Valorum again, I had a look and didn't seem to find it, where is my search going wrong?

Comment: @Seamusthedog - I'd probably VTC as a dupe of this; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19954/whose-bodies-are-the-agents-possessing-when-we-first-see-them?noredirect=1&lq=1. To be honest, I've seen and read pretty much everything there is to read about the Matrix and I've certainly never seen anything to indicate that the Agents are anything other than software, hence why Smith returns to the Source (or rather doesn't return to the Source) once he's destroyed.

Comment: Is there anything to indicate they wouldn't move just as fast if their legs were targeted?

Comment: Closely related question. Not a duplicate. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155211/in-the-matrix-why-didnt-the-agent-dodge-this-bullet

Comment: @HarryJohnston really should proof read things, thanks Harry!

Answer (score 3):

As to what happens when you shoot an agent, well the agent dodges your bullets, unless of course you manage to get a shot from point blank, in which case assuming it is a fatal shot the agent is forced out of the body it is occupying and will most likely enter a different body in the vicinity to continue trying to kill you.

The following is speculative since I seriously doubt there is a canon answer.

As to why agents do not move their legs there are two possibilities.  The first is they would if someone ever shot at their legs but no one fighting an agent ever chose to go for an incapacitating shot so we never see it.

The second is that a leg shot simply would not matter to an agent, the agents are software taking over the avatars of people connected to the matrix, kill the avatar and the agent can no longer utilize it but any damage short of actually removing a limb will most likely not matter to an agents combat effectiveness.  The human body experiences pain but its likely an agent could  still chase you with a bullet in both kneecaps.

Comment: Mechanically it is not possible to run with a bullet in both kneecaps.Perhaps some sort of stilted lumber would be possible at a stretch.

Comment: @Revenant point taken but if the policy is to 'run' when confronted with an agent surly the little advantage of a leg shot would be worth it?

Comment: Presumably the agent would still jump to another host body even if you were lucky enough to score a semi-incapacitating leg shot.